# Perl signal handlers and WIndows

Tags: windows, perl, signals

I am on Windows with Strawberry perl. I have some GUI.pl application which run *script.pl* which run *some.exe*. The perl script works as a proxy for STDIN/OUT/ERR between GUI application and some.exe.
The problem is that I can't kill some.exe process in chain GUI.pl -> script.pl -> some.exe.

*GUI.pl* sends TERM to *script.pl*

```perl
# GUI.pl
my $pid = open my $cmd, '-|', 'script.pl';
sleep 1;
kill 'TERM', $pid;
```

*script.pl* catch 'TERM' and trying to kill *some.exe*

```
# script.pl
$SIG{TERM} = \&handler;
my $pid = open my $cmd, '-|', 'some.exe';
sub handler {
    kill 'TERM', $pid;
}
```

With this scheme, the process of some.exe continues to be executed. I've already learned a lot about the signals but still do not understand how to resolve this problem.

Thank in advance.

---

And one of the solutions it is using of [threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html):

```perl
# script.pl
use threads;
use threads::shared;

$SIG{BREAK} = \&handler;

my $pid :shared;

async {
    $pid = open my $cmd, '-|', 'some.exe'
}->detach;

# 1 second for blocking opcode. After sleep handler will be applied
sleep 1;     

sub handler {
    kill 'TERM', $pid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be wary of use of 'kill' signals on Windows, as they're a `POSIX` thing. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html

But I think the problem here will *probably* be because of [`Deferred Signals`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Deferred-Signals-(Safe-Signals)). Specifically if you send a signal to a process, the interpreter will wait until it's "safe" to process it. In the middle of "some.exe" is unlikely to be.

Using `kill` signals in this way isn't a particularly good form of IPC. See [`perlmonks: Signals Vs. Windows`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=997094) for some useful discussion.

Comment: This explanation is wrong. The deferral process documented in Deferred Signals is not used for Windows signals.

Comment: What I found in this explanation is that I can't handle signal during IO operation.

Answer (score 0):

Signals on Windows are very idiosyncratic. You may have better luck with the `INT` or `QUIT` signals than `TERM`. My extensive research into how Perl and Windows handle signals is summarized [here](https://metacpan.org/source/MOB/Forks-Super-0.80/lib/Forks/Super/Job/OS/Win32.pm#L261).

TL;DR: On Windows, `TERM` can terminate a process in Windows, but it cannot be handled. `INT` and `QUIT` can be handled, and their default behavior is to terminate the process. If you use Windows pseudo-processes (which is what you get if you call `fork` in Windows), then things quickly get more complicated.

Comment: `kill TERM => $pid` [sends Ctrl-Break](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/3ec400f5ce53ea1a56d283bc6bf59e75762df058:/win32/win32.c#l1258), which can be [handled](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/3ec400f5ce53ea1a56d283bc6bf59e75762df058:/win32/win32.c#l2142).  [I can't verify this, because I can't manage to handle any signals for some reason.]